# How to write LINQ query to sql IN

Tags: c#, linq

I want to query my cosmosDB to get List of Documents of type ZonesDO && whose id are in UserPreferance.Zones My UserPreferance class is :

```
public class UserPreference 
    {
        [JsonProperty("zones")]
        public List<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
    }
```

and Zone Class is:

```
public class Zone
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public override Guid Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying this query but not able to complete it.

```
var zones = DbUtil.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri)
     .Where(z => z.Type == typeof(ZoneDO).ToString() && 
     *z.Id in user.UserPreference.Zones.ids*)// here I need the solution
     .AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()` will execute the query and return a list with all results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Contain` method.

```
 var zones = DbUtil.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri)
     .Where(z => z.Type == typeof(ZoneDO).ToString() && 
      user.UserPreference.Zones.Select(x => x.Id).Contain(z.Id)).ToList();
```

Or you can use inline `Where` and `Count`

```
var zones = DbUtil.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri)
     .Where(
        z => z.Type == typeof(ZoneDO).ToString() && 
        user.UserPreference.Zones.Where(a=> a.Id == z.Id).Count() > 0
      ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform select on `Zones.Id` and then check with `Contains` to get desired result

```
var zones = DbUtil.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri)
     .Where(z => z.Type == typeof(ZoneDO).ToString() && 
    user.UserPreference.Zones.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(z.Id))
     .AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be to use the `Any()` operator:

```
var zones = DbUtil.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri)
            .Where(z => z.Type == typeof(ZoneDO).ToString() && 
            user.UserPreference.Zones.Where(x => x.Id == z.Id).Any())
            .AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq providers usually understands basic methods on arrays/collections. Therefore you can use `Contains` method.

```
var zones = DbUtil.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri)
     .Where(z => z.Type == typeof(ZoneDO).ToString() && 
     user.UserPreference.Zones.Contains(z.Id))
     .AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently you have a `user`. This `user` has a `UserPreference` and this `UserPreference` has zero or more `Zones`. It seems that this `user`, and the `Zones` of this user's `UserPreference` is in local memory (not in a database. The `Zones` are IEnumerable and not IQueryable)

Although you didn't specify, it seems that `DbUtil.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri)` returns an `IQueryable<ZoneDO>`

You want all `ZoneDo` that have an Id that is an Id of one of the `Zones` in the one and only `UserPreference` of your user.

In baby steps:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> zoneIds = user.Userpreference.Zones.Select(zone => zone.Id);
IQueryable<ZoneDO> allZoneDOs = DbUtil.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri);

IEnumerable<ZoneDO> requestedZoneDOs = allZoneDOs
    .Where(zoneDo => zoneIds.Contains(zoneDo.Id);
```

Until now no query is performed, nor any enumeration. To perform the query and return the fetched data as a `List<ZoneDO>` use `.ToList()`;

```
List<ZoneDO> documents = requestedZoneDOs.ToList();
```

TODO: if desired put all statements into one big LINQ statement. I doubt whether this will improve performance. It surely will deteriorate readability and thus maintainability.

Did you notice that I did not do your type checking part. This was not needed, because function `CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>` already returns a sequence f `ZoneDo`.

If not, and there are other types in the returned sequence, use `OfType<ZoneDo>` instead of checking on string representation of the returned objects:

```
IQueryable<ZoneDO> allZoneDOs = DbUtil.Client
    .CreateDocumentQuery<ZoneDO>(CollectionUri)
    .OfType<ZoneDo>();
```

`AsEnumerable` is not needed. `IQueryable.ToList()` will perform the query and convert the data to a list.

`AsEnumerable` is only needed if you need the data in local memory to continue with LINQ statements that cannot be performed as IQueryable, like LINQ statements where you call local functions, or LINQ statements that cannot be translated into SQL.

`AsEnumerable` will fetch the requested data per 'page'. So if you  only need the first (few) elements, you don't fetch the complete table, but only the first (few) pages.